# What's the regular expression to achieve the following?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a single regular expression that will replace all `replace me` in the text with `REPLACE ME`, but will leave `dont replace me` untouched.

Text sample:

```
blah replace me blah
blah dont replace me blah
replace me blah blah
blah blah dont replace me
```

I know it can be done an infinite number of ways, but I am looking for a solution utilizing single regex search and replace, so post only if you have one :)

I think it can be done using information from this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html, but I get lost when I read about atomic grouping, lookarounds etc.

I will upvote any solution that works and accept the nicest one. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: could you also explain the idea behind the regex when you post one? Would be nice for people that are not very familiar with the syntax.

You can test your regexes here: http://www.regextester.com/. I am not sure if it is not limited though...

Comment: I had .NET on my mind, but let's say it should work here: http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In `python/perl/c#`:

```
(?<!dont )replace me
```

#### In `vim`:

```
:%s/\(dont \)\@<!replace me/REPLACE ME/g
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions here: http://www.regextester.com/ but neither of them worked (I also tried adjusting the 2nd one by removing redundant \\). Can you write one that will work on http://www.regextester.com/?

Comment: @MichalB.: it doesn't work on regextester.com because regextester.com doesn't know look behind.

Comment: @M42: I supposed that it was caused by its limitation. Is there a way to do it without look behind and other more advanced regex features?

Comment: In `javascript`, (1) replace `dont replace me` to `be5c0d7a-449c-4b6c-b71f-045483133902`, (2) replace `replace me` to `REPLACE ME`, (3) replace `be5c0d7a-449c-4b6c-b71f-045483133902` to `dont replace me`.

Comment: I am aware of such solutions. That's why I deliberately mentioned I am only interested in regular expressions. I like your solution, because it works. I am just curious for other possibilities. E.g. in two steps we can replace `replace me` with `REPLACE ME` and then `dont REPLACE ME` with `dont replace me`. Should also work :)